# XNA Texture2D.FromStream doesn't preserve color in fully transparent pixels

Tags: xna

I'm using the color information in the texture still when the alpha is set to 0.  The PNG file is correctly saved with the color preserved.  If I use the content pipeline and set it to non-premultiplied, everything works fine.  Texture2D.FromStream is documented as non-premultiplied but it's wiping out the color.  When debugging in PIX and looking at the texture, all pixels with 0 alpha are set to black.

Is there a way I can bypass the content pipeline and still keep my color for transparent pixels?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/using-xna-contentpipeline-to-export-a-file-in-a-machine-without-full-xna-gs

Comment: William, you should post this link in an answer and give a short description of it, so OP can accept.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to help too much just now as I don't have code in front of me but I done this a few days ago myself and it had all the correct transparency that was expected. Perhaps it's your image that has an issue? I used a PNG saved using Paint.Net.

As seen in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/07ZEF.jpg the boat, tree trunk and ladder all have transparency which allow them to be on a second layer and the tileset itself is loaded using from stream (User generated content ftw).

So if no-one has answered this before I get to my computer with code then I'll take a look at what I have and post a sample if needed.